# Where are tor control go?

Tags: c++, qt, tor

According to [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhIwJVZl8FQ), I could launch my network connection through Tor by Vidalia, as the image shown

[image: network settings]

But when I download latest tor(windows version, 6.5.2), I cannot find the Vidalia anymore, now tor is start with browser and end with browser. How could I do the same settings as the graph shown on recent tor?

I try to connect through tor by Qt5.6.2 but it always fail(not a recommend way to use QNetworkAccessManager like this)

```
    //9150, 9151 both fails
    QNetworkProxy proxy(QNetworkProxy::DefaultProxy, "127.0.0.1", 9150);
    QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(proxy);
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    //setup the proxy on network manager do not work either
    //manager->setProxy(proxy);
    connect(manager, static_cast<void(QNetworkAccessManager::*)(QNetworkReply*)>(&QNetworkAccessManager::finished),
            [=](QNetworkReply *reply)
    {
        qDebug()<<"push reply";
        QFile file("tor_reply.html");
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)){
            stream<<reply->readAll();
        }
    });
    connect(manager, static_cast<void(QNetworkAccessManager::*)(QNetworkReply*)>(&QNetworkAccessManager::finished),
            manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::deleteLater);
    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.whatsmyip.org/")));
```

I confirm torrc is up and running and do not change any settings of torrc, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I've found out the answer just now, changing proxy settings works:

```
QNetworkProxy proxy(QNetworkProxy::Socks5Proxy, "127.0.0.1", 9150);
```

How to set this up?

1. Go to Tools
2. Click on options
3. Click Advance
4. Click Network
5. Click Settings (please refer image below for steps 3~5)

[image: graph_0]

6. Adjust Manual proxy configuration. I use default option:

[image]